# Error: "Operation must use an updateable query" - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table `Item` in MS Access which looks like this:

```
ID  ProductNumber   ItemNumber  Quantity    UnitPrice
1   P-0001          Item-001        5       $4.00
2   P-0001          Item-002        3       $12.00
3   P-0001          Item-003        2       $6.00
4   P-0002          Item-004        1       $8.00
5   P-0002          Item-005        6       $16.00
6   P-0002          Item-006        2       $7.00
```

I have used a query `Query1` to calculate cost of above table

```
SELECT [Quantity]*[UnitPrice] AS Cost, *
FROM Item;
```

After run query the table looks like this.

```
ID  ProductNumber   ItemNumber  Quantity    UnitPrice   Cost
1   P-0001          Item-001        5       $4.00       20
2   P-0001          Item-002        3       $12.00      36
3   P-0001          Item-003        2       $6.00       12
4   P-0002          Item-004        1       $8.00       8
5   P-0002          Item-005        6       $16.00      96
6   P-0002          Item-006        2       $7.00       14
```

I have used an sub-query `Query2` to calculate `BatchCost`

```
SELECT (Select Sum(T.Cost) 
From Query1 
AS T
Where T.ProductNumber = Query1.ProductNumber) AS BatchCost, *
FROM Query1;
```

After run query the table looks like this.

```
ID  ProductNumber   ItemNumber  Quantity    UnitPrice   Cost    BatchCost
1   P-0001          Item-001        5       $4.00         20    68
2   P-0001          Item-002        3       $12.00        36    68
3   P-0001          Item-003        2       $6.00         12    68
4   P-0002          Item-004        1       $8.00         8     118
5   P-0002          Item-005        6       $16.00        96    118
6   P-0002          Item-006        2       $7.00         14    118
```

I have another table `Prices` which looks like this:

```
ProductNumber   CostPrice
P-0001          $0.00
P-0002          $0.00
```

I want to update `CostPrice` in `Prices` table from `BatchCost` in `Query2` table.

I have used this query:

```
UPDATE Prices INNER JOIN Query2 ON Prices.ProductNumber=Query2.ProductNumber 
SET Prices.CostPrice =  Query2.[BatchCost]
WHERE (((Prices.ProductNumber)=[Query2].[ProductNumber]));
```

But it appears an error: `Operation must use an updateable query`

When I used another field in query like `UnitPrice` instead of `BatchCost` then query works. The problem is in BatchCost field.

Comment: Aggregate queries cannot be used in an UPDATE action. Period. Won't work. Don't save aggregate data unless your db gets so large that calculating the data becomes unbearably slow. Calculate when needed. Otherwise, use VBA to accomplish. However, can use in an INSERT action. So an alternative is to delete records from Prices, and than insert all records, every time you want to update this field.

Comment: What is the best way to save aggregate data? Can you write a piece of VBA code for better understanding? I want to calculate `BatchCost` and update it in `Prices` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, saving this aggregate data is probably a bad idea but if you must...

Open a recordset, loop through records, run UPDATE action. Something like:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ProductNumber, Sum(Quantity * UnitPrice) AS SumCost FROM Item GROUP BY ProductNumber;")

While Not rs.EOF
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Prices(CostPrice) VALUES(" & rs!SumCost & ") WHERE ProductNumber = '" & rs!ProductNumber & "'"
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Or no recordset and no loop with this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Prices"
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Prices(ProductNumber, CostPrice) SELECT ProductNumber, Sum(Quantity * UnitPrice) AS SumCost FROM Item GROUP BY ProductNumber"
```

This second option could be two query objects built in query designer then manually run or call from code (macro or VBA).

Or use DSum() in a query object and call that query (building domain aggregate with conditional criteria in SQL statement in VBA is tricky):

```
UPDATE Prices SET CostPrice=DSum("Quantity*Price", "Item", "ProductNumber='" & [ProductNumber] & "'")
```

Now decide what event procedure you want to put code into, perhaps a button Click.

Comment: The second one is working. I have inserted the data into a temp table and then updated to `Prices` table.

Comment: @Adnan, revised answer to offer 3rd option.